# Is it possible to send emails to a gmail address WITHOUT using GMail as a relay server?

Tags: smtp, gmail

I've been fighting all day trying to properly configure Postfix to get the emails delivered to GMail addresses I finally got it by using GMail's SMTP as a relay server, sadly that server overrides From and Reply-To headers...

With the postfix default configuration I was able to reach hotmail addresses (the emails ended up in the spam folder but that's expected) however I was unable to reach GMail addresses. Do I need to set up my domain at Google Apps? Or am I forced to pay for GMail for Work?

Comment: Why would you use GMail relay servers to send email to GMail recipients? Just have Postfix send them as it would for any other domain.

Comment: @joeqwerty I already tried that, but the emails are not reaching. Am I missing something?

Comment: `I already tried that, but the emails are not reaching` - You need to provide some details? What do your Postfix logs say?

Comment: @joeqwerty LOL. Don't I don't know exactly why, but now the emails are reaching... Maybe sending a couple of messages using GMail as a relay server made my smtp to be "recognized" by Google. The emails are still going to the spam folder, but that happens with a lot of websites anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course send emails to the gmail domain without using the gmail router, this points to a security or blacklist problem with your domain mail exchange, probably you will need to set up and spf record and check that your mail server is not on an blacklist. you can use gmails dianostic tools here:
https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2920052?hl=en

and you can read about setting up an SPF record for postfix here:
https://www.howtoforge.com/postfix_spf

see if you are black listed here:
https://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/

and make sure you are not an open relay mail server, an open relay mail server is one where any IP address can connect to your mail exchange and send mail either from any domain or from your domain, make sure you lock down your mail server to be only accessible by your clients by specifying an SMTP username and password or allowing mail relay by private IP address only.

check for open relay status:

http://www.spamhelp.org/shopenrelay/

you can also try telnet onto your mail servers public IP address and send a mail from the console - this is a good test for Open relay.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652001/send-mail-via-cmd-console